# Wi-Fi constantly slow on MacBook! How to fix?

Tags: macbook-pro, wifi

My MacBook 12" (Macbook 12 2015 Macos BigSur). I also had the problem in Catalina. I have made a clean install, and it didn't help.

It experiences slow Wi-Fi connections constantly! I cannot use apps for streaming like Netflix or sky or any other, because resolution drops from HD 720 to 144p every time. This is very bad!

Some basic tests: Ping 2, Down 255mb, Up 23mb.

I assume there is something going on with the power saving.

Is there a way to disable all power savings? I want to have maximum Wi-Fi performance possible.

Comment: Do you mean a MacBook with a 12" screen? Are you sure your wifi is fast enough and you are close enough to the router? Do other webpages load fast? Try https://www.speedtest.net/de to check your connection. There are power saving options in the system settings but they should not affect browsing performance.

Comment: Yes of course my internet speed is fast enough, the macbook goes is a state of "power saving". You cant watch a streaming video. With other laptop is fine

Comment: Please tell us exactly after you have conducted a speed test what your up and download speeds are. How can you be so sure it goes into power saving mode? Has this behavior always been the case or did you recently do an update like Big Sur. Please provide more detail in your question or it might be closed

Comment: Ping 2, Down 255mb, Up 23mb. Macbook 12 2015 Macos BigSur. I also had the problem in Catalina. I have made a clean install, and it didnt help

Comment: Which *specific* MacBook 12"?  There are models that go from Early 2015 through Mid 2017.  You asked two very different questions - one about WiFi and the other about power settings.  Which one do you want to focus on?  This site works best with one topic per question.  Please [edit] your question to narrow the scope (topic) and provide sufficient details about the problem and what you've done thus far.

Comment: Also Why are you assuming it's "power saving?"  Power saving is related to sleep/hibernation etc.

Comment: Because the macbook does have a 4.5 watt cpu and it is fanless... To me is that apple made something to keep battery life long and heat low. Just my supposition.

Comment: (Rhetorical) How does the power requirements of the CPU and the fact it doesn't have  a fan have anything to do with power and WiFi performance?  It's helpful when asking a question to let go of any preconceived theories you might have because if you focus on a particular aspect, you'll skip over other, more obvious avenues to a solution.

Comment: I totally agree with Allan. Narrow the issue down, e.g. to an app or a certain service. Does this happen only for streaming services or also normal browsing? Is it only in safari or have you tried different browsers? Are other apps running? Maybe try running diagnostics, but **please** edit your question with more info